# Ansible error loading fact, please check content but not always

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I am trying to retrieve the available memory using ansible facts. When I run the code directly on the target machine, it works as expected. However, when I run it from a remote one with ansible, it only populate the data correctly *sometimes*, but fill it with the warning string "error loading fact - please check content" most of the time. I haven't been able to find a pattern, sometimes it works two times in a row, sometimes only once every 4 or 5 attempts.

memory.fact

```sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "{ \"total_mb\": $(free -m | grep Mem: | awk '{print $2*0.95}') }"
```

output when running on the target machine

```sh
/etc/ansible/facts.d$ ./memory.fact
{ "total_mb": 60996,6 }
```

ansible command line

```sh
ansible <hostname> -m ansible.builtin.setup -a "filter=ansible_local"
```

output when it works correctly (I also checked the assigned value, and the it seems to be correct)

```sh
PLAY [Ansible Ad-Hoc] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [ansible.builtin.setup] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [hostname]

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
hostname             : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

output when it doesn't work (I also checked the assigned value, and it's the warning string)

```sh
PLAY [Ansible Ad-Hoc] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [ansible.builtin.setup] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
[WARNING]: error loading fact - please check content
ok: [hostname]

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
hostname             : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

I've tried to run the ansible command with max verbosity level and add debug=true in the config file, but the output is exactly the same whether or not it works (the only exceptions being obviously the assigned value in the ansible_facts json, the warning line and the timestamps).

How can the output of the same command be different? What can be a possible source cause I should investigate on to fix it?

Also, in case I can't find the cause, is there a workaround I could use to tell ansible to retry until it gets a correct value instead of a string? As the task doesn't fail, it doesn't stop the playbook until the value is actually used.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone finds this from a search, I didn't find the reason why the memory fact wasn't collected properly sometimes. However, I found a hacky workaround to make it "work".

I just modified my playbook to add a repeat condition in the facts gathering task, until the fact contains a "total_mb" key.

```yaml
name: regather local facts
    setup: filter=ansible_local
    until: '"total_mb" in ansible_local["memory"]'
    retries: 20
    delay: 2
```

If anyone has an idea of the real reason why this failed in the first place, I'm still interested to know.